# Create a 0-1 dataframe based on matching values in column names and a specific column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I want to re-fill a data frame according to matching values/classes of the column names and information giving in another column.

Here is a hypothetical dataframe:

```
> mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                       C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
> mat.data
 A B C D cat
 1 0 0 0   A
 1 1 0 0   A
 0 1 0 0   C
 0 0 0 1   B
```

I somehow managed to extract matching values by using match function (e.g. `match(mat.data[,5],colnames(mat.data[1:4]))`). However, I couldn't get the output I wanted to have in a reasonable amount of time.

I want to re-fill the 0-1 values based on the a true match between the column names of the data and 5th column (So when the 5th column is A for a given row, I want "1" under the column named "A", and "0" for the others).

For a better explanation, desired output is:

```
> mat.data
 A B C D cat
 1 0 0 0   A
 1 0 0 0   A
 0 0 1 0   C
 0 1 0 0   B
```

Any suggestions to make it clean and less complicated would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach would be to recreate the matrix using `model.matrix` but first ensure that the `cat` variable has levels corresponding to the column names of the original matrix:

```
mat.data$cat <- factor(mat.data$cat, levels = head(names(mat.data), -1))
new.mat <- data.frame(model.matrix( ~  mat.data$cat - 1))
names(new.mat) <- levels(mat.data$cat)

new.mat
  A B C D
1 1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0
4 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. This works really fast on a huge dataset. For increased column numbers, it didn't work tho. However, when I deleted "-1" in here `head = levels = head(names(mat.data), -1))`, it worked. That would be great, If I could understand why or whether it changes the output produced, since I don't have a chance to control it (big dataset issue)?

Comment: If the toy data is representative of the real data there shouldn't be an issue.  Regardless, removing  `-1` from the `head` command completely changes the result (the default is only the first 6 values returned whereas using `-1` means everything but the final value is returned).  Instead, you could use `names(mat.data)` from the toy data, at worst you should have a superfluous column that can be removed (`cat`).

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `data.table::dcast`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mat.data)
mat.data[, cat := factor(cat, levels = names(mat.data)[1:4])]
res <- dcast(mat.data, cat + seq_along(cat) ~ cat, fun.agg = length, fill = 0, drop = c(T, F))
res[, cat_1 := NULL]

# > res
#    cat A B C D
# 1:   A 1 0 0 0
# 2:   A 1 0 0 0
# 3:   B 0 1 0 0
# 4:   C 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the option which reminds me that I need use data.table more often.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `sapply` and relying on logical to numeric conversion:

```
> cat <- c("A", "A", "C", "B")
> lvls <- LETTERS[1:4]
> 
> mat.data <- t(sapply(cat, function(x) as.numeric(lvls == x)))
> colnames(mat.data) <- lvls
> mat.data
  A B C D
A 1 0 0 0
A 1 0 0 0
C 0 0 1 0
B 0 1 0 0
```

Timing of all the answers so far:

```
> microbenchmark(
+   model.matrix = {
+     mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                                         C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
+     mat.data$cat <- factor(mat.data$cat, levels = head(names(mat.data), -1))
+     new.mat <- data.frame(model.matrix( ~  mat.data$cat - 1))
+     names(new.mat) <- levels(mat.data$cat)
+   },
+   dcast = {
+     mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                           C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
+     setDT(mat.data)
+     mat.data[, cat := factor(cat, levels = names(mat.data)[1:4])]
+     res <- dcast(mat.data, cat + seq_along(cat) ~ cat, fun.agg = length, fill = 0, drop = c(T, F))
+     res[, cat_1 := NULL]
+   },
+   outer = {
+     mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                           C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
+     match_cols <- setdiff(names(mat.data), "cat")
+     new.data <- outer(X = mat.data[["cat"]], Y = match_cols, stringi::stri_count_fixed)
+     colnames(new.data) <- match_cols
+     cbind(new.data, mat.data["cat"])
+   },
+   sapply = {
+     mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                           C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
+     lvls <- LETTERS[1:4]
+     new.mat <- t(sapply(mat.data$cat, function(x) as.numeric(lvls == x)))  
+     colnames(new.mat) <- lvls
+   },
+   tidy = {
+     mat.data = data.frame(A = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2)), B = c(0,rep(1,2),0) , 
+                           C = rep(0,4), D = c(rep(0,3),1), cat = c(rep("A",2),"C","B"))
+     mat.data[5] %>% 
+       rowid_to_column %>% 
+       mutate(value=1) %>% 
+       spread(cat,value, fill=0) %>%
+       select(-rowid)
+   }
+ )
Using 'cat' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override (x100)
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
 model.matrix  894.835 1027.983 1185.7946 1173.6940 1313.258  1640.453   100
        dcast 4432.031 4935.079 5603.5700 5290.8000 5725.408 12495.376   100
        outer  508.123  564.671  666.4618  610.9195  758.261  1008.386   100
       sapply  463.534  496.724  611.6146  549.5260  672.997  2526.964   100
         tidy 3936.329 4525.921 5000.3296 4917.7735 5257.409 10660.893   100
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! One problem with `sapply`, time efficiency can get really low if you are working on a big data.

Comment: I just ran microbenchmark on all of the answers so far, and at least for the toy dataset, `sapply` was the fastest

Comment: Glad to see a benchmark. However, microbenchmark of the toy dataset does not scale to larger dataset. If you run the benchmark with a larger dataset, for example `n <- 10000; mat.data = data.frame(A = sample(0:1, n, replace = T),
                       B = sample(0:1, n, replace = T),                          
                       C = sample(0:1, n, replace = T),
                       D = sample(0:1, n, replace = T),
                       cat = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, replace = T))`, you will find `model.matrix` is the most efficient one.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `outer` and `stringi::stri_count_fixed`

```
match_cols <- setdiff(names(mat.data), "cat")
new.data <- outer(X = mat.data[["cat"]], Y = match_cols, stringi::stri_count_fixed)
colnames(new.data) <- match_cols
cbind(new.data, mat.data["cat"])
#  A B C D cat
#1 1 0 0 0   A
#2 1 0 0 0   A
#3 0 0 1 0   C
#4 0 1 0 0   B
```

Without `stringi` you could do

```
new.data <- 1 * outer(X = mat.data[["cat"]], Y = count_cols, `==`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution based on `tidyr::spread`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mat.data[5] %>% 
  rowid_to_column %>% 
  mutate(value=1) %>% 
  spread(cat,value, fill=0) %>%
  select(-rowid)
#   A B C
# 1 1 0 0
# 2 1 0 0
# 3 0 0 1
# 4 0 1 0
```

As you see `D` is not present, it will be there if there's any `"D"` in your `cat` column though.

Comment: Hey thanks, it is very practical where absence of a column (in this case "D") isn't valuable.